# Linear algebra, quadratic forms, positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

The quadratic forms $Q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2+2axy+2bxz+2cyz$,
$a,b,c$ are all real numbers that $abc=0$, I am trying to prove that $Q$ is positive definite iff $a^2+b^2+c^2<1$

So the symmetric matrix is \begin{bmatrix}
 1&  a& b\\ 
 a&  1& c\\ 
 b&  c& 1
\end{bmatrix}
and I am trying to find the eigenvalues of $A$(I hope they are positive), but in the process, I got to the point where the characteristic polynomial of $A=-(\lambda-1)^3+\lambda(a^2-b^2+c^2)-(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2abc$
Then what to do next? how does $a^2+b^2+c^2<1$ fit in here? is something wrong with my characteristic polynomial?

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: yes, but I cannot find $P$ because I don't know the eigenvectors of $A$

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea of what you just said, but thank you.

Comment: is my characteristic polynomial of A right?

Comment: hi, yes, but this question does not require anything about "Sylvester's Law of Inertia", can you check if my characteristic polynomial of A is right?

Comment: never mind, I got it.