# Under what condition does $-(x-1)^3+x(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a^2+b^2+c^2)=0$ have a positive solution $x$?

Tags: polynomials

> Consider the equation $$-(x-1)^3+x(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a^2+b^2+c^2)=0$$ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers. Through what condition does $x$ have positive real solution?

Answer: $a^2+b^2+c^2<1$

How to prove this?

Thank you.

Comment: $x= 1$ is not a solution ?

Comment: It is. when $a^2+b^2+c^2=0<1$ but it does not answer my question.

Comment: @Logan $a = b = c = 666$ and $x=1$.

Comment: @Logan maybe you changed a + into a -?

Comment: @user2661923: Did I change the question? (That wasn't my intention. I mostly just wanted to put the question into the title.)

Comment: @user2661923: I'll leave that for OP to settle.

Answer (score 0):

False, perhaps typo in the query.

Let $k = a^2 + b^2 + c^2.$

The query factors into $(x-1)^3 - k(x-1) = 0.$

Counter example:

$x = 1 + \sqrt{3}, 1 = a = b = c \implies k = 3.$

Comment: from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899601/linear-algebra-quadratic-forms-positive-definite  which has an easy answer by Sylvester Inertia. The OP refused to follow my hints.  I gave up

Answer (score 0):

$$-(x-1)^3+x(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a^2+b^2+c^2)=0$$

$$-\frac{(x-1)^3}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)}+(x-1)=0$$

$$-(x-1) \left[ \frac{(x-1)^2}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)} - 1 \right]=0$$

Focusing in

$$ \frac{(x-1)^2}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)} - 1 = 0 $$

$$ (x-1)^2 = (a^2+b^2+c^2) $$

$$ (x-1) = \pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} $$

$$ x = 1\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} $$

$ 0 < a^2+b^2+c^2 < 1 $ guarantees that both solutions are real and positive.

Comment: Where does the query say that **both** solutions have to be positive?

Comment: Nowhere, but he did post an answer to his own question. I was trying to connect that answer to the proposed problem.

Comment: Seems like your interpretation does represent the most likely intent of the OP.